# How can I echo a value from an oddly structured PHP array (where the name of the array may not be known)?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to reference or echo specific values from an array, but i am unclear on the format for how to write the reference to the array.

I know you can usually echo specific array values using $arrayname[0], etc., but in my example i don't know how to reference the arrayname.

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++){ ?>
<select name="paramrow[<?php echo $i; ?>]" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="-- Select --">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="option1">option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">option 3</option>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

this is what shows when I var_dump($_POST);:

```
array(1) {
    ["paramrow"]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(12) "-- Select --"
        [1]=>
        string(7) "option2"
    }
}
```

So in the above, i'd like to know how to reference "option2". thanks!

Comment: `foreach` then `for`. **Edit:** Do you mean how to reference a string key or because you don't know the key name?

Comment: When you `var_dump()` _what_ exactly?

Comment: The value of the first menu is in `$_POST['paramrow'][0]`, the value of the second menu is `$_POST['paramrow'][1]`, and so on.

Comment: @PatrickQ edited to show var_dump($_POST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use square brackets in an input name, PHP creates an array out of the POST parameters. So `$_POST['paramrow']` is an array, which you can loop over:

```
foreach ($_POST['paramrow'] as $i => $param) {
    echo "In menu $i you selected $param<br>";
}
```

or access directly with indexing:

```
echo "The selection from menu #1 is {$_POST['paramrow'][1]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

$my_array = ['paramrow' => [ "select", "option2" ] ];
var_dump($my_array);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StackOverFlow</title>

    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

foreach ($my_array as $key=>$val) {

    if( is_array($val) ) {
        foreach( $val as $k=>$v) {
            echo "$k = $v";
            echo "<br/>";
        }

    }

}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the structure of the array is like in the code i wrote.
it's an array inside of another array.
so you need to iterate at the first one and the **$val** is a pointer to the inner array [ "select", "option2" ], so when you iterate with : 
`foreach( $val as $k=>$v)` the **$v** contains the "select" and "option2" respectively.